# Table contents inside a popup dialog are not being read by the screen reader NVDA for firefox browser

Tags: wai-aria, accessibility

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYgBc.png) This is what happens the blue marked area is read and nothing after that the red marked area is NVDA speech viewer where what is getting read is getting read. I have a non-empty table but the contents are not read by the NVDA screen reader when used with Firefox browser. It reads every other contents that comes before the table. Below is the sample code that is displayed on the Popup Dialog. Don't want to use role="presentation" as this solves the problem for not reading the table but the screen reader reads as if its a plain text and not as a table.

```
<div role="dialog">
    <h2>This is a H2 content. </h2>

    <p>This is a paragraph</p>

    <table style="width: 80%;">
    <caption class="offscreen">this is the caption for the table.</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">First Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Second Header</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>C11</td><td>C21</td></tr>
            <tr><td>C21</td><td>C22</td></tr>
            <tr><td>C31</td><td>C32</td></tr>
            <tr><td>C41</td><td>C42</td></tr>
            <tr><td>C51</td><td>C52</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a URL we can test? Sometimes these things can affected by code elsewhere on the page, so testing an example where you have recreated the issue is easier and more valuable.

Comment: unfortunately I dont i have added image all it does is on click of the link/button a popup is opened and the contents are read except the "table contents".

Comment: The image offers no help. Here, I made a Codepen to get you started. Fork it and see if you can re-create the issue: http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/RoqmRN

Comment: Thanks for the link it is reproducible.I have created a new link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNbKgb/ 
Please press tab once when the dialog is opened after clicking the button. And yes it reads till [this is a paragraph] and then says Print Me link.

Comment: Any solutions @aardrian ??

Comment: You are not managing focus correctly. That is part of the problem. Regardless, when I switch to Browse Mode (Caps Lock + Space if on a laptop) I can navigate to the table (whether by using the arrow keys or pressing T to bring me to a table) and it is announced correctly. I am using FF with NVDA.

Comment: Yeah in the HTML that I created it's as you said but the actual application gets the focus correctly but the table does not get read but reads perfectly when I press the key Insert + space ( Am using desktop) but I have this requirement of getting it read automatically as soon as the popup gets opened without having to press any key.

Comment: Knowing that requirement, you may have to put focus directly into the table. Bear in mind, that I feel focus should typically go to the control that closes the dialog and this may prove counter-intuitive in practice.